# Reading compressed image data from PNG using libpng

Tags: pdf, png, libpng

How can I read the compressed image data from the IDAT chunk of a PNG using libpng? I have not found a method to do this in the libpng documentation, but I may have overlooked it. Is it somehow possible to use the "unknown chunk" facility for the IDAT chunk?

The purpose of this is that I want to write a very fast PNG-to-PDF converter. Because PDF supports the PNG data format (with each scanline prefixed by a filter-type byte), it should be possible to just copy over the contents of the (concatenated) IDAT chunks and slap the right PDF headers around it (also copying the palette if necessary). This saves a decompression/re-compression step.

If libpng does not provide such low-level access, does any other library provide this functionality? Otherwise I'll just write a PNG chunk reader myself...

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate of that question.  This one wants to know how to extract the IDAT chunk while the suggested duplicate wants to know how to interpret the IDAT chunk.  Something like "pngsplit" (which comes with "pngcheck") can extract the IDAT chunks into separate files.

Comment: Ah right. Well, if you *only* want to unpack the IDAT data (and not process it any further), then libpng is overkill. All you need is a deflate routine (plus some way of reading the raw chunks, but that should be well in the reach of any reasonably good programmer).

Comment: Actually, I don't even want to (un-)deflate. Avoiding that is the point of the optimization I'm thinking about. (This utility will be used in bulk conversion.) Even though writing a chunk reader is quite simple, it's still nice to be able to re-use an existing one, and we use will use libpng anyway in the same program, for example for the less common data formats that PDF, as far as I know, doesn't support (like grey + alpha). I'll look into pngsplit and pngcheck.

Comment: Your solution will work only if the PNG file contains a single IDAT chunk. With multiple IDAT chunks you still have to decompress them and combine them back in a single chunk.

Comment: @iPDFdev: You sure? The spec says "The compressed datastream is then the concatenation of the contents of all the IDAT chunks." So on decoding, you first concatenate, then decode. All chunks concatenated should give a single compressed stream. I see lots of PNGs where all IDAT chunks contain exactly 8192 bytes, that would be weird if they were compressed separately.

Comment: @gpvos I'll check again, I might be mistaken.

Comment: @gpvos My mistake, I was thinking of something else. The chunks need to merged before decompression.

Comment: @iPDFdev: maybe you were thinking of TIFF strips; they do work that way.